# How do I upload a file attachment using POST?

Tags: swift, salesforce

I've created an audio file I want to attach to an "Order" object in Salesforce. The path to the file is properly located at `theSoundPath`.

The following code causes an error that reads: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)'`

I'm encoding the file in base64 as required by the API. But I'm also thinking that's what's throwing this error. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here's the relevant code (using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire):

```
    let encodedSound = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(self.theSoundPath)
    let encodedBase64Sound = encodedSound!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(nil)
    let tokenParam = "Bearer " + theToken // Bearer prefix required by API
    let theWriteURL = theInstance + "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Order/" + self.theOrder + "/Attachment/"
    let URL = NSURL(string: theWriteURL)!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let parameters = [
        "AccountId": "001xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Name": "testfile.aac",
        "Body": encodedBase64Sound
    ]

    var JSONSerializationError: NSError? = nil
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &JSONSerializationError)
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(tokenParam, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in // . . . etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NSJSONSerialization's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/)

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
>     NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

But you try to serialize a NSData object, the result of

```
encodedBase64Sound = encodedSound!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(nil)
```

Instead create a base64 string

```
encodedBase64Sound = encodedSound!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```